# Ajax POST method error/not working

Tags: php, ajax, web

Im trying to make a login for a wepage im working on, but i cant make this specific post to work, i dont know what im doing wrong since ive used it a lot of times, the error is from internal server (error 500), it seems the problem comes from de .php I use because when I comment the code, the error wont show

```
function login() {
    var usuario = document.getElementById('user').value;
    var contra = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "login.php",
      dataType: "text",
      data: { user: usuario, pass: contra }
    });
  }
```

php file....

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$msg = "Error:\n";

if($user!="user"){
   $msg = $msg + "Usuario incorrecto\n"
}
if($pass!="1234"){
  $msg = $msg + "Contraseña incorrecta\n"
}
if($user=="user" && $pass=="1234"){
  header("Location: home.php");
}
echo "<script>alert(".$msg.")</script>";
```

Comment: This is why there are `success` and `error` method properties that you can add to your `$.ajax()` call. Use them.

Comment: `+` is for concatenation is JS. `.` concatenates in PHP.

Comment: Add semicolon at $msg = $msg . "Usuario incorrecto\n"; and $msg = $msg . "Contraseña incorrecta\n"; Also you use + to concatenate instead of ( . )

Comment: Also exit after the `header`. The `.=` can be used in place of adding the variable to every assignment.

Comment: Also echo "<script>alert(' ".$msg." ')</script>";

Comment: right, I got confused there, however it doesnt seem to be the problem, I added succes and error earlier and only error pops

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` for concatenation in php

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$msg = "Error:\n";

if($user!="user"){
   $msg = $msg . "Usuario incorrecto\n";
}
if($pass!="1234"){
  $msg = $msg . "Contraseña incorrecta\n";
}
if($user=="user" && $pass=="1234"){
  header("Location: home.php");
  exit();
}
echo "<script>alert('".$msg."')</script>";
```

Comment: Yes! You should not output anything after a header!

Comment: thanks, i cant believe i passed that... now i dont get the error 500 but post still not working

Comment: I am not sure, but is it possible to read a `<input type="password">`? or does it have security restrictions?

Comment: I use this kind of thing to read password inputs with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the PHP code should look like:

```
$msg = "Error:\n";
if ( isset( $_POST['user'] ) && isset( $_POST['pass'] ) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    if($user!="user"){
        $msg .= "Usuario incorrecto\n";
    }
    if($pass!="1234"){
        $msg .= "Contraseña incorrecta\n";
    }
    if($user=="user" && $pass=="1234"){
        header("Location: home.php");
        exit;
    }
} else {
    $msg .= 'Please enter username and password!';
}

echo "<script>alert(".$msg.")</script>";
```

You need to check the $_POST variable is set correctly. Make sure the file home.php does exist too!

Comment: thanks!, yours looks more professional, any ideas why my POST is still not working?

Comment: Check the output of a simple `<?php var_dump( $_POST ) ; exit; ?>`. What is rally being sent!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you echoing a script tag? You should simply echo $msg and then trigger the alert on the client.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "login.php",
  dataType: "text",
  data: { user: usuario, pass: contra }
}).done(function(message) {
  alert(message);
});
```

);

That might be causing the issue. I would also be absolutely sure that both login.php and home.php exist in the same directory as your login page.

Comment: ooh, this does make the error alerts work, but when user ans password are right, it actually alerts the home.php code, header doesnt work